# Trying to run a section of vb.net code three times before erroring out

Tags: .net, vb.net, error-handling, try-catch

I'm attempting to use try-catch clauses to run a section of code three times before returning an error. Here's what I have.

```
Try

    intTryThree = 0
    'code is here

Catch ex As IO.FileLoadException When intTryThree < 3
    gstrError = gstrError & strErrMessage
    colAdditionalInfo.Add("Tried to run three times", gstrError)
    objErrorLog.Add(ex, cmgErrorLog.ErrSeverity.Fatal, True, colAdditionalInfo)
    Return 1
End Try

        intTryThree += 1
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: is there a question in our future?  Try/Catch are not loop control structures if that is what you want

Answer (score 1):

You could write a loop and check for an exception in the loop, keeping a count of how many times you run into the Catch block.

If the code runs without the exception being raised the loop is exited:

```
    Dim errorCount As Integer = 0
    Dim success As Boolean = False

    Do
        Try
            '
            'some code
            '
            success = True

        Catch ex As Exception
            errorCount += 1
            If errorCount > 2 Then
                'show error message
                Exit Do
            End If
        End Try
    Loop Until success
```